# jQuery how to remove an appended A tag with a given id

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I just appended an A tag and I am trying to remove it, thank you for any help.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="header"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // Append A tag with id= Test1
    $('#header').append("<a href='#' id='Test1'> Test1</a>");

    // Remove the tag - it doesn't work.
    $('#header').remove("a#Test1");
}
```

Comment: use `$('#header a#Test1').remove();`

Comment: I don't want to remove also the header, just the A tag with id Test1.

Comment: The ***slightest*** glance at [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove) answers this question.

Comment: guradio's suggestion above doesn't remove `#header` (but the `#header` and `a` parts of it are completely unnecessary).

Comment: @Ado it is a selector i derive from your selector it means in id header anchor with id Test1 but you can just use `$('#Test1').remove();` as what T.J. is saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  // Append A tag with id= Test1
  $('#header').append("<a href='#' id='Test1'> Test1</a>");

  // Remove the tag - it doesn't work.
  $('#header a#Test1').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="header"></p>
</div>
```

Use `$('#header a#Test1').remove();`

but all you need is `$('#Test1').remove()` to remove that specific element

Comment: why is `#header` needed in selector for the removal? ID's must be unique

Comment: @charlietfl i just derive it from OP original but `$('#Test1').remove()` would be sufficient

Comment: The **only** reason for `#header a#Test1` would be if the OP wanted to avoid removing the element if it weren't an `a` or it weren't inside `#header`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right there might be but the element being removed is using ID that would be invalid HTML mark up then not unique ID

Comment: @guradio: I didn't say he had more than one. Just that it would only make sense if he only wanted to remove it *if* it were inside `#header` and an `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it with this:

```
$('#header').empty();
```

Comment: this will not work if there are other elements in the header that does not need to be removed

Comment: I need to remove a specific tag.

Comment: yeah. agree with u